# Calculate deceleration of a balls compression as it hits the floor, from air pressure and elasticity

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, pressure, collision, elasticity

A ball bounces for 2 reasons:

1. A bouncy ball is made out of rubber, as that shape deforms and presses into the ground it restores itself to normal (because it elastic) and that converts the velocity from down to up.
2. A football is filled with air, the air pushes out in all directions on the ball. if you throw the ball at the ground it will try to deform and press in on the gas, the gas pushes back and therefore the ball bounces back up.

now the volume of a sphere being flattened from side is

$$V(x) = (\pi/3)(4 \cdot \text{radius}^3 + x^3 - 3\cdot\text{radius}\cdot x^2 )$$
where $x$= distance the sphere has been deformed by

But how do I know how far it will compress?

I think I need to work out its initial speed as it comes into contact with ground and then do a suvat equation for the balls deceleration to describe  the material of the ball and the internal airpressure both resisting the deformation and slowing the ball down to 0.

So if I have a ball weighing $1\ \mathrm{kg}$ and just before coming into contact with the floor is traveling vertically down by $10 \ \mathrm{m/s}$ how might I come up with a suvat equation for its deceleration to 0?

ps) I have made assumptions throughout this, if any of my assumptions are wrong please tell me.

Comment: *now the volume of a sphere being flattened from side is* You have a reference for the formula you cite?

Comment: top of the 4th page in this https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.01282.pdf

Comment: You could add that information to your question, so it is self-contained.